# How do I cancel a previous Facebook reauthorize call?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

A quick question about the Facebook SDK for iOS. I'm trying to implement the functionality for a user to grant my app access to extended permissions.

While the code works fine when the user accepts the extended permission request (from the Facebook iOS app the user gets redirected to), I'm having trouble detecting when the user has returned to the app while having neither accepted the permissions, or clicking cancel then returning to the app.

If I click 'Cancel' and multitask back into the app, there is nothing logged and nothing shown on-screen. When I try to re-authorize again, the Facebook SDK throws an exception:

> FBSession: It is not valid to reauthorize while a previous reauthorize call has not yet completed.

While I can catch the exception, it still doesn't help as I can't figure out how to stop the previous call in order to allow the user to try to re-authorize again.

Here's the code I'm using at the moment:

```
@try {
    [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPermissions:[self requiredPermissions]
                                             behavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self fetchUserPermissionsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL extendedGranted) {
                if (extendedGranted) {
                    [self setCanPostToActivityStream:YES];
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception);
}
```

Now, the issue is not with the code above - the code works fine. The issue I'm having, again, is cancelling the **previous** re-authorize call when the user doesn't return to the app successfully after allowing permissions. The Facebook SDK as it is doesn't seem to alert the app of this situation in any way.

Comment: are u cleared your last session?

Comment: Old Q, but are you implementing - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation ?

Comment: Yes I am implementing that. The Facebook login wouldn't work without implementing that. The Facebook SDK physically doesn't notify me if the user cancelled the re-authorize which is a real problem!

Comment: John Rogers, Were you able to resolve this issue? If so, can you let me know how you did it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your App's delegate, when `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application` is invoked, you need to make a call to the active session's `handleDidBecomeActive` method. Once you do that, the completion handler associated with your `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions` call will be invoked, and will provide the appropriate error.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should see coming back from the SDK is an error from the reauthorize completion handler.

```
{
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason" = "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonUserCancelled";
}
```

I tested something similar with the following setup: Xcode 4.5, iOS 5, Authorize against m.facebook.com. After an initial authorization I put code to hit reauthorize, then clicked Cancel and got this error.

```
    [FBSession.activeSession
     reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
     defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Success case
        } else {
            // Check the error, info
            // [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason"]
        }
    }];
```

If you are not seeing this then it is a bug and you may want to file it with Facebook.

Comment: Hi C Abernathy!
if we ask for more permissions using reauthorizeWithPermissions, then is our previous session expired? or it remains same with same token??? do we need to re-assing appDelegate.session and appDelegate.facebook.session?

it show's the "login" button in permissions UI rather than "allow" button.

Comment: The previous session is not expired. You want to use the updated session with the new permissions so re-assign the permissions if you need to based on how your authorization code is set up.